# setting hidden variable to entity

Tags: java, jsf

now I need help with setting variable.
I have two entities Season and Tournament, tournament belongs to season.
So now I created one season and I see the list of this season. I have here one button "select" which should save actual season to session scope:

```
public String selectSezona(Sezona sezona){
        this.sezona = sezona;
        return "index";
    }
```

so now I have selected one season and now I wanna created tournament in this season but I dont wanna select season so I write this:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{turnaje.turnaj.setSezona(sezony.sezona)}" />
```

this is hidden input text which should assign actual season to this tournament but this wont work :( . Error is: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException . I see that season is set because I see its name. How tou figure this issue ? please help
thx

edit:

I also have getter and setter in tournament

```
@ManyToOne
private Sezona sezona;

public Sezona getSezona() {
        return sezona;
    }

    public void setSezona(Sezona sezona) {
        this.sezona = sezona;
    }
```

but why  should  I have method setSezona without parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a `selectSezona(...)` method, but not a `setSezona(...)`.

In fact, your hidden field would require a property as its value, not a method.
Your `setSezona(...)` doesn't return anything, however, JSF needs a way to get the initial value.
Thus, you'd need to change the expression to `#{turnaje.turnaj.sezona}`.

You'd still get an error, since JSF can't convert between `String` and `Sezona`, so you also need to provide a converter to your hidden field.

Comment: but why  should I  have method setSezona without parameter ?

Comment: hm I try this but this still didnt work. how program know what to set in tournament season when I change it to this #{turnaje.turnaj.sezona}

Comment: @huid You'd need to either do this via Javascript, i.e. set the value of the hidden field, bind the setter to a select box or other input, or just set in the server side. I assume `selectSezona(...)` does the change, so why not just call `setSezona(...)` in that method?